# IOS container view swipe between them

Tags: ios, view

I have a design for an app which has a solid background that doesn't move and then a series of pages on top of this that you can swipe through. When you swipe I would like it to appear that the background stays put and the new panel moves from left to right as you swipe replacing the last one.

For this I am assuming that I would use a container view for each of the views that I want to display, and link them kind of like this.

https://spin.atomicobject.com/2015/09/02/switch-container-views/

The bit I am missing is the swipe and if this is the right way to do this kind of thing.

Any pointers in the right direction would be great

Comment: Use `UIPageViewController` -> https://www.appcoda.com/uipageviewcontroller-storyboard-tutorial/

Comment: There are lots of pod available to implement functionalities like this please refer following Pod it might help you 

https://github.com/hirohisa/PageController

Answer (score 0):

You can use UIPageViewController, added static background on it.

here is example:

```
class YourCustomPageViewController: UIPageViewController {
    // for example purpose i will use only two view controllers, you can use more
    var firstVC: CustomViewController?
    var secondVC: CustomViewController?

    //MARK: Private Properties
    fileprivate var pages: [UIViewController] = []

    //MARK: Object Life Cycle
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.view.backgroundColor = .white
        dataSource = self
        delegate = self

        //This is your static background, which will be added on page view controller and will not be scrollable
        let bgImageView = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "bg"))
        bgImageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        self.view.insertSubview(bgImageView, at: 0)
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            bgImageView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.leftAnchor, constant: 0),
            bgImageView.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.rightAnchor, constant: 0),
            bgImageView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.topAnchor, constant: 0),
            bgImageView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.bottomAnchor, constant: 0)
        ])

        firstVC = (self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "FirstVCIdentifier")) as? CustomViewController
        secondVC = (self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SecondVCIdentifier")) as? CustomViewController
        pages.append(firstVC!)
        pages.append(secondVC!)

        setViewControllers([firstVC!], direction: .forward, animated: true, completion: nil) 
}

//MARK: UIPageViewControllerDataSource & UIPageViewControllerDelegate
extension YourCustomPageViewController: UIPageViewControllerDataSource, UIPageViewControllerDelegate {
    func pageViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerBefore viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {
        guard let index = pages.firstIndex(of: viewController) else { return nil }
        let previousIndex = index - 1

        return previousIndex >= 0 ? pages[previousIndex] : nil
    }

    func pageViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerAfter viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {
        guard let index = pages.firstIndex(of: viewController) else { return nil }
        let nextIndex = index + 1

        return nextIndex < pages.count ? pages[nextIndex] : nil
    }
}
```

after that you can build your CustomViewController with custom ui... and it will be scrollable over PageViewController.

Don't forget transition style from pageCurl to scroll.